# Look and feel problems encapsulating a ReactJS embedded application using Material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, wordpress, material-ui, embed

I am embedding a ReactJS application using Material UI styled components inside a Wordpress page. I am using webpack for transpilation of the js.

I have produced the bundle of the embedded version of the application and I am importing and instantiating it in the following way

```
<script src="https://<domain url>/path/myapp.app.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadApp() {
    window.MyApp("my-app-div");
  }
</script>
```

my-add-div corresponds to the id of the div where I want my application appears

Everything is working under the functional point of view.

My problem is related to the look and feel of the application that is influenced by the css of the wordpress theme.

I have tried to use the components CssBaseline and ScopedCssBaseline but the rendering seems to ignore them.

I have also tried those directives to reset the css styles but it did not work

```
#my-app-div {
all: initial; /* blocking inheritance for all properties */
}
#my-app-div * {
  all: unset; /* allowing inheritance within #my-app-div */
}
```

I have found a possibile solution prefixing all the css of the Material UI style component with the id of the my-app-div div, in this way the css of the styled component has more priority than the css coming from the wordpress theme.
I have also found a plugin that could help in this but it is not compatible with the latest version of stylis https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylis-plugin-extra-scope

Does anyone has any suggestion to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a prefix to your material UI class for production build
using the following approach.

```
import { createGenerateClassName, StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core'

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
      seed: 'xyz',
      productionPrefix: 'abc-',
    })

function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
         ...
    </StylesProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have tried but it seems to do not change the generated code. We are using mui material version 5.4.3.
Anyway, using generateClassName I think the generated code changes the class names, instead I need to add the css selector in the generated styles definition.

For instance currently I have the css style defined in this way
<style> css-z2n7vq {...my css rules}</style>

Instead I would like to have
<style> #my-app-div css-z2n7vq {...my css rules}</style>